# Setting WpfToolkit datagrid column editing style

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, styles

How to make a single datagrid column editable if a particular condition is true?

I'm using MVVM pattern in my application.

```
 Model ::

public class Book : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int BookId {get; set;}

    public string Title {get; set;}

    public string SerialNumber {get; set;}

    public bool CanEditSerialNumber {get; set;} // Allows editing serialnumber if this property is set to true.

}
```

ViewModel::

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     DbEntities _dbEntities; // ADO.Net entity model.

     public ObservableCollection<Book> Books {get; set;}

     public MyViewModel()
     {
         this.ListAllBooks();
     }

     public void ListAllBooks()
     {
         _dbEntities = new DbEntities();

         var book = from _book in _dbEntities.Book
                    select new Book()
                    {
                       BookId = _book.BookID,
                       Title = _book.Title
                       SerialNumber = _book.ISBN,
                       CanEditSerialNumber = _book.HasSerialNumber
                    }

          Books = new ObservableCollection<Book>(book);
          OnPropertyChanged("Books");
     }

}
```

View::
    I bind the ObservableCollection Books to a WpfToolkit datagrid.

```
<WpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="dgBooks"
                     ItemSource = {Binding Books}
                     ....>

     <WpfToolkit.DataGrid.Columns>

         <!-- Here I want to display Book Title and SerialNumber -->   

         <CustomControls:LabelTextBoxColumn Binding={Binding Title}
                                            ElementStyle={StaticResource myLabelStyle}
                                            />

         <!-- This column should be editable only if CanEditSerialNumber property is set to true. -->
         <CustomControls:LabelTextBoxColumn Binding={Binding SerialNumber}
                                            ElementStyle={StaticResource myLabelStyle}
                                            EditElementStyle={StaticResource myTextBoxStyle}/>

     </WpfToolkit.DataGrid.Columns>
```

Is it possible to make only a single datagrid column editable based on a boolean value?

Answer (score 0):

For now, this is what I have done:

```
   <CustomControls:LabelTextBoxColumn.EditElementStyle>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

           <Style.Triggers>
               <Trigger Property={Binding CanEditSerialNumber} Value="False">
                 <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True">
               </Trigger>
           </Style.Triggers>

        </Style>

   </CustomControls:LabelTextBoxColumn.EditElementStyle>
```

Does not work perfectly, but will do for now. Any other suggestions are welcome.